# Why am I only able to style this element inline? And styling it in styles.css does not do anything

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style this form, but I'm only able to do it inline. Everything else is working fine, but this specific form I can only style it inline. (I am also using xampp and php if that is relevant).

```css
.chat_container {
  display: none;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 31px -10px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0vw;
  width: 17.1vw;
  background-color: rgba(9, 45, 79, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999999;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: orange;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat_container" style="position: fixed;bottom: 0px;right: 0vw;width: 17.1vw;background-color: rgba(9, 45, 79,0.7);z-index: 9999999;border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-style: solid; border-color: orange; border-bottom-style: none; border-right-style: none;">

  <form name="form1" style="padding-left: 15px;padding-top: 15px;">
    Nickname: <input type="text" name="uname" style="padding-bottom: 10px;" /> <br />
    <br />

    <div id="chatlogs" style="color: orange; padding-left: 5px;">
      <p>Please wait...</p>
    </div>

    <textarea id="msg_area" name="msg" style="width: 90%;border-radius: 5px; border: none; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;"></textarea><br />
    <a href="#" onclick="submitChat()" id="chat_button" style="display:none;">Send</a><br />
  </form>

</div>
```

If I remove the html inline styling, the whole element loses its styles.

Answer (score 1):

Remove CSS Property `display: none` on your CSS file

```css
.chat_container {
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 31px -10px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0vw;
  width: 17.1vw;
  background-color: rgba(9, 45, 79, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999999;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: orange;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat_container">

  <form name="form1" style="padding-left: 15px;padding-top: 15px;">
    Nickname: <input type="text" name="uname" style="padding-bottom: 10px;" /> <br />
    <br />

    <div id="chatlogs" style="color: orange; padding-left: 5px;">
      <p>Please wait...</p>
    </div>

    <textarea id="msg_area" name="msg" style="width: 90%;border-radius: 5px; border: none; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;"></textarea><br />
    <a href="#" onclick="submitChat()" id="chat_button" style="display:none;">Send</a><br />
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Already did. The chat just goes to the top of the page like it's there, but without any css. (The display:none was there because of some javascript i wrote)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I don't know why, but I CTRL +f5 the browser, cleared site cookies, then closed project on sublime and reopened it and it's okay now.